# Can I create Ansible role in one project and then import it in diferent projects

Tags: ansible

I want to build Ansible role that then can be used by different Ansible project/s. I want to avoid coping code of role every time. Is there some better way? And I do not want to publicly publish code of the role.

Comment: https://galaxy.ansible.com/?

Comment: Yes, I did not mention that I do not want to publicly publish role. I am looking something like import role from git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes you can](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/using/installing.html) import a role directly from a Git repo.

```
# requirements.yml file
- src: <link to git repo>
```

Then execute the command:

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

Or even simpler:

```
ansible-galaxy install git+<link to .git version of repository>
```

These are of course only two of many ways. Check the link above for more details.